# Menu Class is missing in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

I'm developing a task tray application in .NET Core, and I want to create a simple menu to access the application features. However, the required Menu class is not available in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

The official documentation shows that control is available [Menu Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menu?view=netcore-3.1).

How to get the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per this, Menu is no longer available in .NET Core 3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms-breaking-changes

> The following types are no longer available:
>
> Menu

The recommended action is also listed there.

> For **Menu**, you can either use: **ToolStripDropDown** or
>   **ToolstripDropDownMenu**.
>
> For **MainMenu**, you can use: **MenuStrip**
>
> For **MenuItem**, you can use: **ToolstripMenuItem**

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is wrong. The Menu class have been deprecated and is no longer available in the .NET Core framework. As per [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/2091).

To create a Menu it is required to use the [Menu Strip Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menustrip?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Dang, that’s a shame. I preferred to use `Menu` because it used the OS-provided native menubar instead of `MenuStrip` which was custom-rendered.

Comment: This issue has been raised https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/2543

Answer (score 2):

We have fixed the documentation issue that was showing the control as available in .NET Core 3.1. Thanks for raising this issue!
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menu#applies-to

The suggested replacements for the controls removed in .NET Core 3.1 can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/porting/winforms-breaking-changes#recommended-action.

Thanks!